# How does the compiler/runtime determine a lambda expression's type?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

**I was wondering how the the compiler/runtime determines a lambda expression's type?**

For example, the following `System.Linq` `Select` extension method (not select query)

```
//var recordIds = new List<int>(records.Select(r => r?.RecordId ?? 0));
//var recordIds = new List<int>(records.Where(r => r != null).Select(r => r.RecordId));
var recordIds = new List<int>(records.Select(r => r.RecordId));
```

is defined as

[`Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TResult>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx)

and so takes the lambda `r => r.RecordId` as a `Func<TSource, TResult>`.

**How is the lambda's type determined, and once it is, is it simply cast to that type?**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference

Comment: Every object has a type during runtime.  Some are standard types like integers and string while others are non standard that is used by linq.

Comment: Lambda doesn't have a type by itself, it can only be inferred from context. So when inference is done - it gets an inferred type (not casted to it, because there is no type to cast from).

Comment: @jdweng I thought C# had only value and reference types? Do you mean there are specific linq reference types? Or, are you making the distinction between static and dynamic types?

Comment: When you have an enumeration the compiler assigns a type to every enumeration as well as classes.  The same occurs with linq types during compilation.

Comment: @jdweng What are  you talking about?  There are no special LINQ types.  LINQ is just a collection of methods in the `Enumerable` and `Queryable` classes.  If it wasn't in the language, you could write them all yourself just fine.  They're just regular static methods.  There is no special types there at all.  The question is also about lambdas, LINQ doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: @Servy Perhaps jdweng is referring to the LINQ query statements?

Comment: @samosaris But they aren't special types, and have nothing to do with types.  It's merely a set of rules for performing transformations of expressions *regardless of their types*.

Comment: MSDN describes it as follows : The query operators over relational data (LINQ to SQL) build on the integration of SQL-based schema definitions into the common language runtime (CLR) type system. This integration provides strong typing over relational data while retaining the expressive power of the relational model and the performance of query.  Not sure why they use SQL when the page is referring to just linq : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx

Comment: @jdweng Okay, so what about that involves special magic types?  That just means that LINQ is a bunch of code that performs SQL queries and maps the results into regular old C# objects, with types that are just like any other object.

Comment: Not like all object, just non standard objects.  Net library has two type object.  Early Binding and Late Binding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I was wondering how the the compiler/runtime determines a lambda expression's type?

It is rather complicated. Implementing this feature was the "long pole" for the version of Visual Studio that shipped C# 3 -- so every day that I was over schedule on this was a day that VS would slip! -- and the feature has only gotten more complicated with the introduction of covariance and contravariance in C# 4.

As others have noted, consult the specification for exact details. You might also read the various articles I've written about it over the years.

I can give you a quick overview though.  Suppose we have

```
records.Select(r => r.RecordId)
```

where `records` is of type `IEnumerable<Record>` and `RecordId` is of type `int`.

The first question is "does `IEnumerable<Record>` have any applicable method called `Select`?  No, it does not. We therefore go to the extension method round.

The second question then is: "is there any static type with an accessible extension method that is applicable to this call?"

```
SomeType.Select(records, r => r.RecordId)
```

Let's suppose that `Enumerable` is the only such type. It has two versions of `Select`, and one of them takes a lambda that takes two parameters. We can automatically discard that one. That leaves us with, as you note:

```
static IEnumerable<R> Select<A, R>(IEnumerable<A>, Func<A, R>)
```

Third question: Can we deduce the type arguments corresponding to type parameters `A` and `R`?

In the first round of type inference we consider all the non-lambda arguments.  We only have one.  We deduce that `A` could be `Record`.  However, `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, so we make a note that it could be a type more general than `Record` as well.  It cannot be a type that is more specific than `Record` though.

Now we ask "are we done?"  No. We still don't know `R`.

"Are there any inferences left to make?"  Yes. We haven't checked the lambda yet.

"Are there any contradictions or additional facts to know about `A`?"  Nope.

We therefore "fix" `A` to `Record` and move on.  What do we know so far? We have:

```
static IEnumerable<R> Select<Record, R>(IEnumerable<Record>, Func<Record, R>)
```

We then say OK, the argument must be `(Record r) => r.RecordId`.  Can we infer the return type of this lambda knowing that?  Plainly yes, it is `int`.  So we put a note on `R` saying that it could be `int`.

Are we done?  Yes.  Is there anything else we can make a deduction about?  No.  Did we infer all the type parameters?  Yes.   So we "fix" `R` to `int`, and we're done.

Now we do a final round that checks to make sure that `Select<Record, int>` does not produce any errors; for example, if `Select` had a generic constraint that was violated by `<Record, int>` we would reject it at this point.

We've deduced that `records.Select(r=>r.RecordId)` means the same thing as `Enumerable.Select<Record, int>(records, (Record r) => { return (int)r.RecordId; } )` and that's a legal call to that method, so we're done.

Things get rather more complicated when you introduce multiple bounds. See if you can figure out how something like a `Join` works where there are four type parameters to infer.

Comment: By the way, what happened to the "Excessive Explanation" series on the inference in ML?

Comment: @Joker_vD: I got SUPER BUSY at work and never finished it!  Hopefully I'll find some time in 2018.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best place to look for such information is the language spec:

Section 7.15

> An anonymous function is an expression that represents an “in-line”
>   method definition. *An anonymous function does not have a value or type
>   in and of itself, but is convertible to a compatible delegate or
>   expression tree type*. The evaluation of an anonymous function
>   conversion depends on the target type of the conversion: If it is a
>   delegate type, *the conversion evaluates to a delegate value
>   referencing the method which the anonymous function defines.* If it is
>   an expression tree type, the conversion evaluates to an expression
>   tree which represents the structure of the method as an object
>   structure.

The above explains the nature of lambda expressions, basically that they have no types by themselves, unlike say, an `int` literal `5`. Another point to note here is that the lambda expression is not *casted* to the delegate type like you said. It is *evaluated*, just like how `3 + 5` is evaluated to be of `int` type.

Exactly how these types are figured out (type inference) is described in section 7.5.2.

> ...assume that the generic method has the following signature:
>
> T<sub>r</sub> M`<`X<sub>1</sub>…X<sub>n</sub>`>`(T<sub>1</sub>
>   x<sub>1</sub> … T<sub>m</sub> x<sub>m</sub>)
>
> With a method call of the form M(E<sub>1</sub> …E<sub>m</sub>) the
>   task of type inference is to find unique type arguments
>   S<sub>1</sub>…S<sub>n</sub> for each of the type parameters
>   X<sub>1</sub>…X<sub>n</sub> so that the call
>   M1…S<sub>n</sub>>(E<sub>1</sub>…E<sub>m</sub>)becomes
>   valid.

The whole algorithm is quite well documented but it's kind of long to post it here. So here's a link to download the language spec.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: I have it downloaded, can be lead me astray though.

Comment: @samosaris I've added an excerpt that describes exactly what type inference is trying to do. Hopefully this helps. The entire algorithm is quite complicated. Don't worry if you don't understand it. Try reading it again.

Comment: Oh, right, a lambda is an anonymous function, so that should've been my starting point into the spec.

Comment: @samosaris: You might consider buying the printed specification; there are annotations I and other experts put in it that explain the tricky bits in more detail than the online spec.

Comment: @sαmosΛris: The 2010 edition is on Amazon and, vexingly, I think it was the last edition published on paper. It's a lot of work to put together the print version and it is hard to compete with the free online documentation.

Comment: @EricLippert Sorry I removed my comment after doing some more searching and found what I thought were newer editions, but they too are from 2001... Are the revisions printed too, as addendums maybe (books are nice when the internet is too distracting or screens are too bright)?